# How to validate route requests in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel-9

I've got a route like this:

```
Route::get('/{library}/{media}/{genre}/{title}', [BookController::class, 'showBook']);
```

And controller:

```
class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function showBook(Request $request, $library, $media, $genre, $title)
    {
    //??
    }
}
```

Now how do I validate all these parameters to make sure they are valid slugs before I use them in an Eloquent query?

Should I extend FormRequest and add rules there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find or fail method on each model:

```php
Library::findOrFail($library);
Media::findOrFail($media);
// etc
```

This will return a collection, or fail out if false.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions